# Error trying to retrieve data when using multiple dropdowns from same source

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am having an issue with dropdown3 in my app. Powerapps says it can't retrieve data from the network, but can read the same datasource for dropdowns 1 and 2.

My app has 3 dropdowns, each corresponding to a column in my Excel data source, Table1:

| Owner | C C | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Own1 | 1234 | Desc1 |
| Own1 | 2345 | Desc2 |
| Own1 | 2345 | Desc3 |
| Own2 | 9876 | Desc1 |

Dropdown 1 has **items = Distinct(Table1,Owner)** which works great. Shows Own1, Own2 when dropdown is opened.

Dropdown 2 has **items = Distinct(Filter(Table1, Owner = Dropdown1.Selected.Result),'C C')** which also works great. When dropdown is opened shows only CC's for the selected Owner. (Eg. Own1 selected in dropdown1, dropdown2 shows 1234, 2345)

Dropdown 3 has **items = Filter(Table1, 'C C' = Dropdown2.Selected.Result)** and returns Description. I've also tried **items = Filter(Table1, Owner = Dropdown1.Selected.Result, 'C C' = Dropdown2.Selected.Result)**. Both of these throw the error: "Error when trying to retrieve data from the network".

I am so stuck on this. Any ideas on what the issue is?